# How to upload photos in iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating a practice address book app and I would like to add the functionality of the user uploading his picture as well. I have searched the net but I could not find a useful tutorial on how this can be achieved.

If someone knows of a good tutorial about uploading images please share.

One more thing, if the user uploads his/her image, I want the image to be stored in core data as well, so that it can be displayed in the Table View Controller and a Update View controller where the user can upload a new image and replace the previous one.

Any good tutorial explaining this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please do some research before you ask any question.You need to use the UImagePickerController Like so:

You need to add these Delegates to your viewController

```
UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate.
```

Once you want the user to choose an image

```
[[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose media type"
                             delegate:self
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                    otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Library", nil] showInView:self.view];
```

This will show a UIActionSheet so the user can choose from the camera or library

After the user has chosen one of the options, the UIActionSheet delegate method will be called

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            break;
        case 1:
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            break;
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Here you get the user choice at ether add the camera or add the library

Now, after the user picks a photo (library / camera), the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods will be called

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

chosenImage is the image the user has chosen from the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: What is the apps status in CoreData? do you have everything setup?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply....not feeling well for the past couple of days due to flu....will work on it today and let you now if I have any problems....and thanks for the detail answer, I was searching the web using wrong key words. After looking at ur tutorial I found out how and what I need to search and was able to find a tutorial as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest you to use AFNetworking

```
    NSString *BASE_URL = ... //Your server base url
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
    NSString *path = ... //Your relative path
    NSDictionary *params = @{};//Your params
    [operationManager POST:@"" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if (mediaFile) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:mediaFile name:@"name" fileName:@"fileName" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];
```